# A chain of modal dialogs

Tags: qt, modal-dialog, qml, qtquick2

In imperative C++ I can simply to ask user a couple of a questions in a row using `QDialog`s. Depending on answers of the user ("Yes", "No", "OK", "Abort") I can move further.

But in QML, due to its declarative nature, it seems a hard task. Still it is possible to create a bunch of dialogs, but state (information), which depends on answers should be stored somewhere between `onAccepted`/`onRejected`/... events. It is especially hard, if there is many interaction with C++ code (models/singletones).

Is there any general approach/technique/idiom to make easy a creation of something like an "installator" using only a chain of modal popup windows?

Comment: Don't think this is opinion-based. There must be a technique.

Comment: Make "wizard" window. Put a stack widget on it and show your questions there.

Comment: Absolutely, it is possibly. I second Dmitry S. There is only one shortcoming with modern QML components available. Look at QML Settings. It is form-scoped: only pertains to current UI item. I made similar QML MySettings to write common app context pretty much same way as QSettings C++ class does (it uses it, in fact).

Comment: You're doing it wrong in imperative C++ to start with, since you're reentering the event loop and that's a waste and a bug source. And it's super hard to handle any other behaviors than a linear set of steps, so you'll subcionsciously try to shove it to fit that limited form even if it's nonsense. Factor out the logic into a statechart and then it'll be equally easy in both C++ and QML, and it'll be also much easier to prove that it behaves the way you wish it too. Plus free documentation for your project :)

Comment: And addition to @KubaOber's idea: you can even use Qt's SCXML module to load the statechart in c++, making it even easier

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, like others have mentioned here before, For longer chains of events you would really need to use something like a state machine.

That being said, in practise, most things related to Dialogs involve at most 2-3 levels of questions. ***Callbacks*** are a nice fit for that:

The basic Api You're looking for is something along the lines of:

```
g_dialogs.confirm({
                     title: 'Discard unsaved changes?',
                     message: 'You have unsaved changes here.\n' +
                              'Are you sure you want to open a new file?'
                  },
                  function(result){
                    if(result) {
                      g_dialogs.fileDialog({title: 'Select an Image'},
                                           function(fileUrl){
                                             loadFile(fileUrl)
                                           })
                    }
                 })
```

Where g_dialogs is pointing to the global instance of the Dialogs item. You may even use QML singletons for it.

**Dialogs.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Item
{
    property var dialogs: []
    property var callbacks: []

    /**
     * Creates a modal dialog pointed by the dialogSource qml file.
     * For this functioanlity to work, the dialogSource MUST be an instance of Dialog component
     * properties are the objects that will be passed on to the dialogSource' component
     * property must not contain a key called 'dialogId'
     * callback is the callback function that will be called with the result,
     * once the user finishes interacting with the dialog. (eg. confirms/dismisses and event)
     **/
    function showDialog(dialogSource, properties, callback) {
        if (properties === undefined)
            properties = {}

        if (properties['dialogId']) {
            console.error('You cannot use the property name dialogId')
            return -1
        }

        properties["dialogId"] = dialogs.length

        var dialog
        var component = Qt.createComponent(dialogSource)
        var result = -1

        if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
            dialog = component.createObject(parent, properties)
            callbacks.push(callback)
            dialogs.push(dialog)
            result = dialogs.length - 1
        }
        else {
            console.error(component.errorString())
        }

        return result
    }

    /**
     * Internal function used by Dialog
     * to return the result to the original caller via. the callback
     */
    function returnDialog(index, result) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= callbacks.length)
            return

        var callback = callbacks[index]
        var dialog = dialogs[index]

        callbacks.splice(index, 1)
        dialogs.splice(index, 1)

        if (dialog !== undefined)
           dialog.destroy()

        if (callback !== undefined)
            callback(result)
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method to create a confirmation dialog where the user is presented with a yes/no question
     * Asks the user whether he wants to confirm/reject an action.
     * properties can be an Object of {title: 'Window title', text: 'Text', icon: ''}
     * Once the user finishes interacting with dialog, the callback will be called with the result
     */
    function confirm(properties, callback) {
        properties["title"] = properties["title"]
                              ? properties["title"]
                              : qsTr("Warning")
        properties["text"] =  properties["text"]
                              ? properties["text"]
                              : qsTr("Are you sure?")

        properties["standardButtons"] = StandardButton.Yes | StandardButton.No

        return showDialog("MessageDialog.qml", properties, callback)
    }

    // Convenience wrapper around FileDialog.qml
    function fileDialog(properties, callback) {
        return showDialog("FileDialog.qml", properties, callback)
    }

}
```

Where, Each dialog is an instance of **Dialog.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item
{
    id: modalDialog

    readonly property int dialogId: 0

    signal done(var result)

    onDone: g_dialogs.returnDialog(dialogId, result)
}
```

eg. **MessageDialog.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import '.'

Dialog
{
    property alias title: dialog.title
    property alias text: dialog.text
    property alias icon: dialog.icon
    property alias standardButtons: dialog.standardButtons

    MessageDialog
    {
        id: dialog

        modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
        standardButtons: StandardButton.Yes | StandardButton.No
        icon: StandardIcon.Warning

        onAccepted: done(true)
        onYes: done(true)
        onNo: done(false)
        onDiscard: done(false)
        onRejected: done(false)
    }

    //Variables in other windows don't seem to reflect the property changes in here.
    //So show the window only after all the properties are set.
    Component.onCompleted: dialog.visible = true
}
```

eg. **FileDialog.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import '.'

Dialog
{
    property alias title: dialog.title
    property alias fileUrl: dialog.fileUrl
    property alias fileUrls: dialog.fileUrls
    property alias folder: dialog.folder
    property alias modality: dialog.modality
    property alias nameFilters: dialog.nameFilters
    property alias selectExisting: dialog.selectExisting
    property alias selectFolder: dialog.selectFolder
    property alias selectMultiple: dialog.selectMultiple
    property alias selectedNameFilter: dialog.selectedNameFilter
    property alias shortcuts: dialog.shortcuts
    property alias sidebarVisible: dialog.sidebarVisible

    FileDialog
    {
        id: dialog
        onAccepted: {
            if (selectMultiple) done(fileUrls)
            else done(fileUrl)
        }

        onRejected: done(null)
    }

    Component.onCompleted: dialog.visible = true
}
```

P.S The nice thing about this api is that these callback functions are nice Javascript closures, so you won't have to pass around pesky references when using this approach inside ListView/Repeater delegates.